# Set the colour of albumArt to layout background

Tags: android, android-layout, colors, uiimageview, albumart

I have a new question.I'm having a now playing activity. In this activity I have to set the colour of albumArt in the imageview to the layout of the activity(like Walkman). I have no idea about it.Please can anybody guide me.